# I am seeing an error in Downloading Packages for Build Tools 27.1.0 in Android Studio 3.1.4?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin

[image: Error Screen Shot in Android Studio 3.1.4]

When I downloaded a project from the GitHub

First, I was trying to have the latest API as per the https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions

but it was showing the same error, So I degraded API versions but still the same error

I created a new dummy project & tried to work on the same 27.1.1 but to my surprise, it worked here. In my main case, There is no Logcat as Gradle Build in not done.

Please help out on the issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 27.1.0 is not downloading.. Is that the issue sir?

Comment: you should install build tools 27.1.1 and rebuild your project again!

Comment: @UmangBurman ji, yes as the screenshot is showing it is not.

Comment: @M.G I have downloaded the project from Github & I am not creating a new project So I tried initially with 28.0.0 when it failed then I tried for 27.1.1 as per the https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions, But When I created a fresh new app on the android studio I used 27.1.1 & it worked fine. Gradle sync was perfect.

Comment: @UmangBurman ji thanks, I will try this & let you know. This never happened before this is weird actually.

Comment: Haan na.. Sometimes we never know lol

Comment: @UmangBurman ji, it didn't work. I already have it. If you see in the new attached images in the question.

Comment: Okay rahul ji, just try this.. uninstall from here i mean SDK Tools then install from the project.. If this doesn't work you can install it from SDK Tools again..

Answer (score 0):

IMO, Rahul, you must see consider installing them separately from SDK Tool section in your SDK Manager. Do not click the project's "install and bla bla bla..."

Try and let me know if my answer was helpful.. if not I'll delete the answer.